# URL Source code in PC doesn't match in Phone HTTP

Tags: java, html, http, twitter

Using this URL : https://twitter.com/cnn/status/824165048436322304

When I check the view-source in my PC web browser I can find og:type like

```
<meta  property="og:title" content="CNN on Twitter">
```

but when I try to view the source-code using Java in my Phone I can't find this og:type or og:title properties

Java code (works fine) does show me the full source but no og:type properties:

```
    String urlContent = "";
    try {
        System.out.println("I'm trying to connect");

        URL urlCon = new URL(urlStr);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlCon
                .openConnection();
        System.out.println("Ok im here ");
        con.setReadTimeout(6000);

        if (con.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            System.out.println("Page is ok!");

            urlContent = readStream(con.getInputStream());


            return urlContent;

        } else {
            return urlContent;
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return urlContent;
}
```

Comment: Web servers can provide different content for different user agents.

Comment: So is there any trick to make my agent for phone inputstream the same as in PC agent?

Comment: There's no trick to it. You can pass all kinds of headers when making an `URLConnection`.